# JSON string to actual JSON

Tags: json, .net-core

Using .Net core 2.2, I am building an API that returns JSON data from my stored procedure (using `FOR JSON PATH`), I return a value that looks like:

```
[{"ID":213,"SizeCode":"Small"},{"ID":257,"SizeCode":"S/M"},{"ID":214,"SizeCode":"Medium",},{"ID":215,"SizeCode":"Large"}]
```

So when I map it to my object to return from the API

```
public class Details
{
    public string SizeChart { get; set; }
}
```

,it returns this:

```
"[{'ID':213,'SizeCode':'Small'},{'ID':257,'SizeCode':'S/M'},{'ID':214,'SizeCode':'Medium',},{'ID':215,'SizeCode':'Large'}]"
```

I don't want the double quotes around it, so I figure the actual property shouldn't be a string. Is there a better data type to use or a way to return without the double quotes?

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how you're generating that JSON? also are you sure this isn't just the debug view of the variable? (VS debugger always puts a string in "" to visualize it as string in the inspector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse `string` into `JSON` object (actually in your case - [JArray](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm) as it is an array) and return it from your `API`:

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
```

So it might look like

```
public class Details
{
    public string SizeChart { get; set; }

    public JArray SizeChartJArray { 
        get { 
            return JObject.Parse(SizeChart);
        }
    }
}
```